# AWS Application Load Balancer fails to process request body for content encoding gzip and content type application/json

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, aws-alb

I am trying to send a gzipped json as POST request body to AWS Application Load Balancer, which calls AWS Lambda.

When I set the content type request header as application/json, I get `502 Bad Gateway` error as response and AWS Lambda does not get invoked.

I am using following curl command.

`curl -v -s --data-binary @samples/small-batch.json.gz -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://sub.domain.com/batch`

Am I sending invalid request headers?

My AWS Lambda code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("event = ", event)
    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({ 'success': True }),
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
```

**Update**

If I place request with empty content type, then Lambda gets called successfully.

```
curl -v --data-binary @samples/small-batch.json.gz -H "Content-Type: " -H "Content-encoding: gzip" -X POST https://sub.domain.com/batch
```

If I make request with `application/gzip` content type then Lambda gets called successfully.

```
curl -v --data-binary @samples/small-batch.json.gz -H "Content-Type: application/gzip" -H "Content-encoding: gzip" -X POST https://sub.domain.com/batch
```

The 502 error is occurred only when I request with Content Encoding as `gzip` and Content Type as `application/json`. But as per my understanding these are valid headers.

**Update 2**

From the documentation I found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html

> If the content type is one of the following types, the load balancer
>   sends the body to the Lambda function as is and sets isBase64Encoded
>   to false: text/*, application/json, application/javascript, and
>   application/xml. For all other types, the load balancer Base64 encodes
>   the body and sets isBase64Encoded to true.

I think because of this, header `Content-Encoding: gzip` can not be coupled with header `Content-Type: application/json`. I think something is going wrong in ALB while calling Lambda.

Comment: I'm sure there will be cloudwatch logs for the lambda invocation (result with error). Do you see any ?

Comment: @JamesDean That is the problem. I don't see any cloudwatch logs. That's why I came to the conclusion that Lambda does not get invoked.

Comment: Does the function work as expected with out `Content-Type` but everything else the same?  That appears to be what you are saying, which does not lend itself to any good explanation.  Does your body exceed 1 megabyte either before or after decompression? Does `cat samples/small-batch.json.gz | gzip -d` correctly decode the file with no errors?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `cat samples/small-batch.json.gz | gzip -d` correctly decode the file. The size of original json is approx 10 kb.

Comment: Turn on logging at the ALB level by editing the Attributes  > Access Logs > Turn on S3 logging of ALB

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a problem with header `Content-Encoding: gzip` & `Content-Type: application/json` but it could be a problem with the binary data size (which could be more than 1 MB) that you are sending.

According to AWS documenation, Lambda has limitation in request and response payload while using with ALB.

- The maximum size of the request body that you can send to a Lambda function is 1 MB.
- The maximum size of the response JSON that the Lambda function can send is 1 MB.

Please refere:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html